# Opencv (JS) select finger area from image

Tags: opencv

I'm coding ionic app that allow user to take finger photo and upload to server.

My objective is I would like to find any solution to select area of finger and cut it of from background (please see image below).

[image]

I found that opencv can do that (https://gigadom.in/2011/10/) but I would like to find the way to to with javascript or NodeJS.

Any idea for this.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV has a JS library: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d84/tutorial_js_usage.html

This means you can take many of the python implementations of this logic and port it to JS.

Technique 1 to remove the background using color thresholding: [How to remove the background of an object using OpenCV (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63629177/how-to-remove-the-background-of-an-object-using-opencv-python)

Technique 2 to remove background using contours:
[Removing Background Around Contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295209/removing-background-around-contour)

Your use case may require a combination of these techniques and some fine tuning.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make it on the fly? like I'm using camera preview on mobile app and once user point camera to finger, it will remove bg can preview.

Comment: @Giffary Did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Background removal is a generic concept in computer vision, usually associated with removing areas that are not moving.

Perhaps what you are looking for is something related to object detection, and as a result, removing everything that is not the detected object.

Try to research something like that: "Finger Object Detection"

Or if the application is in a controlled location, perhaps the other solution discussed here, with the solution of removing everything that is not of a certain color, united with morphology, will have some result.

Anyway, I believe this solution should be applied on the server side. Applying this solution on the frontend will require a lot of performance-related care.

Anyway², look at how opencv's background removal works on a moving video.

[image: OpenCV-Flow BGRemove Sample]

App Link: https://online.opencvflow.org/

Project Link: https://opencvflow.org/